# Ruby print hash key and value

Tags: ruby, hash, each

I'm trying to print key : value
Currently I keep getting errors when I try to run my codes.

The code:

```
output.each do |key, value|
    puts key + ' : ' + value
end
```

I can not figure out a way to do this on the same line. I've tried various implementations, like using the << symbol. I've also played around with print, using multiple puts statements, and appending both values into a string and printing that.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I made an assumption based on the little information you provided but it would help if you gave the exact error and the contents of the hash using `output.inspect`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I can not figure out a way to do this on the same line."  Are you trying to output multiple key : value pairs on a single line?  Can you provide an example of the output you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Depending on the contents of your `Hash`, you might need to convert the `key` to a string since it might be a symbol.

```
puts key.to_s + ' : ' + value
```

Or, what I would suggest doing, use string interpolation:

```
puts "#{key}:#{value}"
```

The reason you are getting an error, if `key` is indeed not a string, is because it is trying to call the method `+` on whatever `key` is. If it does not have a `+` method, you will get an error.